# How can I pass an object key/value pair to a template in Vue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, templates, pug

This is what I have so far -- everything is ok except that the links go to `http://localhost:5173/[object%20Object]` and I think I've hit a mental wall.

My component:

```js
<template lang="pug">

.nav-container
  .nav-controller
    ul.navbar-nav
      li.btn(v-for="(value, key) in myObject" :key="value")
        a.nav-link.nav-item(type='button' :href='{value}') {{key}}
</template>

<script>
const sections = {
  Home: "/",
  Programming: "/programming",
  Finance: "/finance",
};

export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  data() {
    return {
      myObject: sections,
    };
  },
};
```

I realized it can be shrunk down and simplified but thats the current state of my project based on trial and error to understand how things work, not final.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what I did -- but basically messing around with it in normal HTML and then converting it into pug through a website generator;

```
<template lang="pug">
link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65' crossorigin='anonymous')
.nav-container
  .nav-controller
    ul.navbar.nav
      li.btn(v-for='(value, key) in myObject')
        a.nav-link.nav-item(type='button' :href='value') {{ key }}
</template>
```

it works...

Comment: Its because in your example code you wrapped the links href value inside object!

`:href='{value}'`

In the fixed version its not wrapped inside object `:href='value'`